# RealtimeSignalProcessor is not working on update query in Django

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have used haystack with elasticsearch. Haystack version is 2.1.0 with Django 1.5

I have added below code in setting.py

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
  },
}

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

While inserting data its working properly, but result in SearchQuerySet is not updated on update query.

I also refer below question, but not works.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028964/django-haystack-realtimesignalprocessor-updates-index-but-uses-old-index-for-se

Can please anybody tell me what should I done wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The signal to reindex is not sent when using the update method, it's done only when the save or delete methods are called: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signal_processors.html#realtime-realtimesignalprocessor